# Looping based on a spreasheet using python (in ArcGIS 9.3)

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3

Here's what I am trying to do: I want to move feature classes from one `.gdb` (OLD) to another (NEW), but only the feature classes that are present in an excel spreadsheet.

1. read from excel spreasheet (old name column)
2. compare to old .gdb feature classes to find match
3. move matched feature class to new .gdb
4. rename feature class in new .gdb based on new name in excel spreadsheet (new name column)
5. continue doing the above until the end of the spread sheet

Comment: I would convert the .xls file to a .txt file and then when reading in each line, split by comma (make sure none of your cells have commas so it doesn't throw off your split).  Add the value from "old name column" by line.split(",")[column number in excel spreadsheet goes here] (indexes start at zero) to a list and loop through your list.  Then leverage arcgisscripting at 9.3.

Comment: Instead of reading a text file and splitting lines, I would recommend exporting to CSV and using the Python [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to read the file. This automatically splits the lines into lists or dictionaries depending on which reader you use.

Comment: If you install [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) you don't even need to go as far as saving as a CSV - you can just connect directly using something like `conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=%s;Readonly=1' % excel_path, autocommit=True)`

Comment: I may be mistaken, but can't you [connect directly to a XLS](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/body.cfm?id=760&pid=746&topicname=Working%20with%20Microsoft%20Excel%20files%20in%20ArcGIS&tocVisable=0) in 9.3 and then just run a `SearchCursor` directly on it? I'm running 10.0 or I'd just test it.

Comment: @Chad, I think you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) library installed (there's an installer for Python 2.5 in their Downloads section) it's a simple matter of looping through each row of the Excel sheet. Something like:

```
#import libraries
import arcgisscripting
import pyodbc
import os.path

#set paths to documents
old_gdb = "path_to_old.gdb"
new_gdb = "path_to_new.gdb"
excel_path = "path_to.xls"

#initialise arcgis
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

#create a connection to the excel sheet
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=%s;Readonly=1' % excel_path, autocommit=True)

#**
#Create the cursor
#**
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Loop over all the rows returned from a cursor execute
for row in cursor.execute('select * from "Sheet1$"'):
    #we can reference columns by their name in the row object
    if gp.Exists(os.path.join(old_gdb, row.old_name_column)):
        gp.copy_management(os.path.join(old_gdb, row.old_name_column), os.path.join(new_gdb, row.new_name_column))
    else:
        print "Some warning"
```

If you don't want to use pyodbc, it should be easy enough to substitute in a csv reader or otherwise instead of the connection to the .xls. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried running your code and it came up with this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\SETI\Python_Script\excelTest.py", line 18, in <module>
    for row in cursor.execute('select * from "Sheet1$"'):
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

what does it mean? Please keep in mind I have little experience with python scripting for ArcGIS

Comment: @Viktor Whoops! My bad! I forgot to put in the creation of the cursor object. It's in the code now. Sorry about that! As far as the error goes, a `NameError` typically means an object hasn't been created before you try and use it.